# Java list of list of String

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy

I have list with Versions (Strings), I want to make List of List for version of every release

```
List<List<String>> releases = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

```
def list = ["7.5.9", "7.5.8", "7.5.7", "7.5.6", "7.5.5", "7.5.4", "7.5.3", "7.5.2", "7.5.1", "7.5.0", "6.5.1", "6.5.0"];
```

I want to have collection for every release
First list of versions 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2,
Second list of versions  1.5.0, 1.5.1
Third list of versions 2.0.0 ... and so on for every release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the release versions have two digits, the input list may be grouped by the prefix (thus getting a map of `String, List<String>`) using `Collectors.groupingBy` and then the list of the versions is sorted using `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```java
List<List<String>> versions = new ArrayList<>(
        list
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                str -> str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.')),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    (List<String> lst) -> { lst.sort(String::compareTo); return lst; }
                )
            ))
            .values() // Collection<List<String>>
        );

versions.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```java
[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2]
[2.0.0]
[3.0.0, 3.0.1]
[1.5.0, 1.5.1]
[2.5.0]
[3.5.0]
```

The code above assumes the format of the release part in the version always has at least two dots (major and minor versions).

If some versions may not comply with the initial format (e.g., there are `0.1` or `1.0.2.1`), the following grouping condition should work fine:
`str -> str.substring(0, str.indexOf('.', str.indexOf('.') + 1) + 1),` - the release prefix is assumed to contain at least 1 dot `.` and at most two dots.

---

Example Groovy implementation:

```
def list = ["3.5.0", "3.0.1", "3.0.0", "2.5.0", "2.0.0", "1.5.1", "1.5.0", "1.0.2", "1.0.1", "1.0.0"]

def versions = new ArrayList<> (list.groupBy { 
    it.substring(0, it.lastIndexOf('.')) 
}.values())
.each { it.sort() }

versions.each {println it }
```

Output:

```
[3.5.0]
[3.0.0, 3.0.1]
[2.5.0]
[2.0.0]
[1.5.0, 1.5.1]
[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2]
```

---

**Update**

The following Groovy code fixes sorting issues and also removes the highest version as well as the empty results:

```
def list = ["3.5.0", "3.0.1", "3.0.0", "2.5.0", "2.0.0", "1.5.1", "1.5.0", "1.0.1", "1.0.0", 
"1.0.10", "1.0.11", "1.0.2", "1.0.3", "1.0.4", "1.0.5", "1.0.6", "1.0.7", "1.0.8", "1.0.9"]

def versions = new ArrayList<> (
    list
        .sort() // sort initial list
        .groupBy {
            it.substring(0, it.lastIndexOf('.')) 
        }.values()
)
.each { it.sort{ a,b -> Integer.compare(
    Integer.parseInt(a.substring(a.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)), 
    Integer.parseInt(b.substring(b.lastIndexOf('.') + 1))
)}.removeAt(it.size() - 1) }

versions.removeIf { it.empty } // remove empty sublists if any found

versions.each {println it }
```

Output

```
[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.10]
[1.5.0]
[3.0.0]
```

Comment: do you know how to make this algorithm to work for groovy

Comment: do you how to sort it to be like
[3.5.0]
[3.0.1, 3.0.0]
[2.5.0]
[2.0.0]
[1.5.1, 1.5.0]
[1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0] and remove the hieghst version for every release, if it is only 1, remove it, expect [3.0.0] [1.5.0] [1.0.1, 1.0.0]

Comment: if there are more version, they are not sorted correctly, for example [1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9,

Comment: I fix the sort. Change "it.sort()" with "{ a,b -> a.compareToIgnoreCase b}"

Comment: Sorting with `compareToIgnoreCase` won't work either.

Comment: how to make the script work if I use Itrerable<Component> instead list. I update question

Comment: If you have a new question, you should create it as such.  Now your question looks totally different than the original one.

Comment: this is the new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848149/groovy-iterable-component-remove-the-highest-version pls help me

Comment: @ivankolev, you may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848720/13279831)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("3.5.0");
    list.add("3.0.1");
    list.add("3.0.0");
    list.add("2.5.0");
    list.add("2.0.0");
    list.add("1.5.1");
    list.add("1.5.0");
    list.add("1.0.2");
    list.add("1.0.1");
    list.add("1.0.0");

    Collections.sort(list);
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (String e : list)
        map.computeIfAbsent(e.replaceFirst("\\.\\d+$", ""), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(e);
    List<List<String>> releases = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    System.out.println(releases);
}
```

output:

```
[[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2], [1.5.0, 1.5.1], [2.0.0], [2.5.0], [3.0.0, 3.0.1], [3.5.0]]
```

Comment: do you know how to make this algorithm to work for groovy

Answer (score 1):

Use streams:

```
List<List<String>> versions =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(/* a function which extracts the version */))
        .values()  /* gives you a Collection<List<String>>, stop here if you don't need it as an actual List */
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

An example of "a function which extracts the version" for the values shown could be:

```
value -> value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Down below is a pure idiomatic Groovy version w/o Java streams and other strange constructs:

```
def list = ["7.5.9", "7.5.8", "7.5.7", "7.5.6", "7.5.5", "7.5.4", "7.5.3", "7.5.2", "7.5.1", "7.5.0", "6.5.1", "6.5.0"]

def collector = {
    List asInts = it.split( /\./ )*.toInteger()
    [ sum:asInts.reverse().withIndex().collect{ v, ix -> 10.power( ix ) * v }.sum(), major:asInts[ 0 ], original:it ]
}

def listOfSublists = list.collect collector sort{ it.sum } groupBy{ it.major } values()*.collect{ it.original }

assert listOfSublists.toString() == '[[6.5.0, 6.5.1], [7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3, 7.5.4, 7.5.5, 7.5.6, 7.5.7, 7.5.8, 7.5.9]]'
```